# SELECT last row if USER is found

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a log table in SQL Server. Table is structured this way:

```
Unique  ProblemID  ResponsibleID  AssignedToID  ProblemCode

155     155        0282                         4
156     155                       0900
157     155                                     3
158     155                       0147          1
159     159        0111                         2
160     159                       0333          4
161     159        0900                         1
```

So basically we log all problems and who was responsible/had to deal with the problem.
I need a query that would find which problems one person was involved in:

For example:

1. Person with ID 0900 was involved in both 155 and 159.
2. Person with ID 0282 was involved in 155 only.
3. Person with ID 0333 was involved in 159 only.

Also I forgot to mention that I need to filter the last row of ProblemID by the ProblemCode. For example find problemID where person is involved, but there the ProblemCode in the last log line of that problem is 1 (Which means the problem is now closed).

Furthermore, I was working with query:

```
    select ProblemID, EntryTime, ResponsibleID, ProblemCode, AssignedToID
    from (select ProblemID, EntryTime, ResponsibleID, ProblemCode,  AssignedToID,
    row_number() over(partition by ProblemID order by EntryTime desc) as rn
    from myTable) as T
    where rn = 1 and ResponsibleID = '00282' OR AssignedToID = '00282' 
    and veiksmoid <> 4
```

However, it ONLY matches the last rows.

Comment: What you want is a simple WHERE clause; what did you try already that didn't work?

Comment: These simple queries return too many rows I only want the unique ProblemID's.

Comment: last row always shows the current status of the mistake.

Comment: why 900 onvolved in both 155 and 159, how you considered ProblemCode when decided that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives  you all the problems that a person 0900 dealed with and that have problemCode=1 in their last line. I can't test it so there might be some errors.

```
SELECT problemID FROM <table> t1
WHERE problemID IN  (
      SELECT problemID FROM <table>
      WHERE (ResponsibleID = 0900 OR AssignedToID = 0900))
AND problemCode = 1
AND unique = (SELECT MAX(unique) FROM <table> WHERE problemID = t1.problemID)
```

Comment: Please review the third query

Comment: Yeah this query is ok for finding the ID's but makes it impossible to filter by last row. For example if I want to find only the mistakes where ProblemCode in the last line is 1...

Comment: Can you try now, the last one. I might have misunderstood what you are trying to do since this is a simple addition to query.

Comment: The problem with last query is that the number 1 can be in several rows before that.. Only the last row in a particular mistake matters.

Comment: Can you try now, the last query. It will probably need some optimizing, but it might get you somewhere.

Comment: This looks better, thanks for trying, but are you sure this is for MSSQL I am getting syntax error at unique.

Comment: To be honest, I'm using Oracle so I'm not sure about MSSQL syntax. But "unique" refers to your field "unique" that you posted in OP. Substitute it for the correct column name maybe if that's the case?

Comment: I take this as acceptable answer until something better comes up!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ag.UserId, ag.ProblemID
FROM(
   SELECT ProblemID, ResponsibleID as UserId
   FROM Table 
   WHERE ResponsibleID IS NOT NULL

   UNION ALL

   SELECT ProblemID, AssignedToID  as UserId
   FROM Table 
   WHERE AssignedToID IS NOT NULL
) ag
GROUP BY ag.UserId, ag.ProblemID
```

Comment: I guess with some tweaking this would do. Though this does not directly check what is in the last row of a particular mistake...

Comment: @GEMI : yep does not check, because for me entire logic of ProblemCode is not clear. it woudl eb great if you can clarify it on PersonId=900 example

Comment: It is more of a Last Action in that particular mistake. If mistake 155 was closed a line is created with number 1. If mistake was redirected a line with number 9 is created. So in order to be up to date on certain things i need to be able to filter those last lines.

Comment: So you need only entries with ProblemCode = 1?

Comment: I need to be able to specify the ProblemCode. For example WHERE ProblemCode <> 4 or ProblemCode = 9 etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this query could help:

```
SELECT ProblemID
FROM LOGTABLE
WHERE (ResponsibleID = x) OR (AssignedToID = x)
```

where LOGTABLE is the name of the table, and x is the Person's ID.

Comment: in this case you probably can use where `x in (ResponsibleID, AssignedToID)`

Comment: Using the IN version does work.  Yet I wouldn't use it.  People are more familiar with `variable IN (constant, constant)`, and using this version wouldn't provide any performance benefit.  It's not wrong, I wouldn't say it's bad either, I just think that using OR is more familiar and so I'd use that in preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct problemid
   from YourTable
   where 
         ( Responsible = 0900
      OR AssignedToID = 0900 )
      AND ProblemCode <> 1
```

Comment: Thanks this is good, but does not take into account the last problem code of a mistake.